# SQL Server : combine daterange and list of product codes

Tags: sql-server, combinations

I did try searching this, but have no idea how to express it correctly, so I'm hoping someone here might be able to help.

I have two tables, product and daterange.

```
CREATE TABLE product 
(
    Code    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Price   money
);

CREATE TABLE daterange 
(
    yyyymm varchar(6) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO product (Code, Price)
VALUES ('10001J',3.68), ('10002K',7.23), ('10003L',4.72);

INSERT INTO daterange (yyyymm)
VALUES (201507),(201508),(201509),(201510);
```

The list I want to produce is this:

```
YYYYMM  Product
---------------
201507  10001J
201507  10002K
201507  10003L
201508  10001J
201508  10002K
201508  10003L
201509  10001J
201509  10002K
201509  10003L
201510  10001J
201510  10002K
201510  10003L
```

Basically, create a combination of all products and all dates. I have no idea whether I even need the daterange table, or whether it can be done with code alone. And yes, I could create the combination in Excel or whatever, but I'm hoping to build it into a larger dynamic query.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How about a `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: And now I feel like an idiot. Thanks Felix. Haven't come across that one before :)

Comment: `I have no idea whether I even need the daterange table` With regards to this, a dates table isn't a bad thing to have on hand anyway, IMO (though with actual dates, not varchars - it's easy to convert them for your needs at some later point). Then you can just select whatever date range you need from that table without having to create it each time. The same with a numbers table.

Comment: Handy to know. Thanks ZLK

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Felix for pointing out a join I hadn't really used before.

```
SELECT yyyymm, code FROM product CROSS JOIN daterange
```

worked a charm.

Comment: Actually, you sort of _have_ used this before.  You could also just use `INNER JOIN` without an `ON` clause (try it).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen An inner join would always need an on clause. It's just the on clause could be `ON 1 = 1` or something.

Comment: @ZLK In MySQL an inner join without an on clause is permissible and is identical to a cross join.  Apparently not in TSQL.